# Отктет идентификатор в переменной SNMP

Tags: любой-язык, протоколы, snmp

Есть такая переменная `ipInDiscards;1.3.6.1.2.1.4.8`, которая имеет тип `Dart.Snmp.SimpleType.Counter`. SNMP служба в WindowsXP при запросе этой переменной возвращает набор октетов:

```
0x41 0x02 0x4d 0xb2
```

Первый октет в двоичном виде:

```
01     0   00001
класс тип  тег
```

тег `00001` значит что тип BOOLEAN. Но само значение занимает два октета,  но само значение явно не булевское

Класс `01` значит что тип прикладной.  Что это означает? Что отправитель заложил свой смысл в тег `00001` и он уже не является типом BOOLEAN? Значит должно быть соглашение о том, что значение типа  `Dart.Snmp.SimpleType.Counter` в протоколе  `ASN.1  BER` имеет идентификатор 0x41. Или это не правильные рассуждения?

Что означают другие классы `10`, `11`?

Comment: А почему вы думаете, что первый байт надо как то декодировать ? Что то мне подсказывает, что это 4 байта самого значения счетчика ...

Comment: Это спецификация `BER`, первый байт идентификатор, второй длинна, остальные само значение

Comment: Как у них все сложно ... в общем если бы класс был 0, то тег=1 означал бы boolean. но так как класс=01, то теги для класса application описаны в других стандартах. В RFC2578 https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2578.txt тег=1 для application заявлен как counter32. описание классов есть например тут http://rsdn.org/article/ASN/ASN.xml, как и в других источниках описаны только названия. изначально это описано в "ITU-T Rec. X.680". Все классы кроме 0 надо искать в стандартах на протоколы, использующие это кодирование